# Explaining the Upper-bound for Big-O (e.g. O(n))?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

Given the following real function: $ f(n) = n+1 $, where $f(n) \subseteq O(n)$, I don't understand how this can show that $O(n)$ is an upper-bound for $f(n)$. Especially when you graph it; $f(n)$ shows up above $O(n)$.

Is there any other example of a function that is part of $O(n)$ that can demonstrate how the Big-O works as an upper-bound?

Thank you.

Comment: What is $O(n)$ and what do you mean by $f(n) \subseteq O(n)$?

Comment: Big O denotes "type of increase". sin(1/x) is O(1), because it flattens out for large x, and behaves like a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function being $\mathcal{O}(n)$ implies that there exists a positive constant $c > 0$, so that for "large" $n$ (i.e. $n \geq n_0$ for some $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$), it holds that

$$
   f(n) \leq c n
$$

In your case, notice that $n + 1 \leq 2 n \Rightarrow f(n) \leq 2n, \forall n \geq 1$.

Comment: Does $n_0$ mean initial input/size?

Comment: @MaxHusky no, it is just meant to denote that you are considering "large" inputs $n$, as the classes $\Omega(n), \Theta(n), O(n)$ are all asymptotic classes. In other words, you don't have to be able to bound your function $f(n)$ for "small" values of $n$ (a.k.a smaller than some $n_0$).

Comment: Is $cn = 2n$,because $2n$ satisfies $f(n) \leq c n$? And is there any way to show this on a graph?

Comment: Yes, you can set $c = 2$ to prove $f(n) \leq cn$. What do you mean by showing it on a graph? It should be clear by the slopes of $n + 1$ and $2n$ that the latter will be asymptotically bigger as $n \to \infty$.